# Hasbyte function returns a null value

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm trying to extract data in SSIS via a OLE DB Source, the query i'm using has a hashbyte function, which in SSMS returns the hasbyte as expected. However in SSIS, i'm getting NULL values returned.

The function is as follows;

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5','AA12BC') AS ColA
```

In SSIS, if I click preview the following is returned

System.Byte[]

Which when written to a table, returns NULL.

Comment: could you please share your data flow task? you will not see the actual output when preview, but it should load data into the destination table

Comment: Are you sure the source column is mapped to the destination? (My apologies for the semi-insulting question, but it could be the issue.)

Comment: What version of SQL Server is your Source db?

Answer (score 0):

Even with the data preview you're seeing, the correct data format should still be applied when inserting to the destination table with no unexpected nulls if the follow steps are taken:

- Cast the data as varbinary, i.e. `SELECT CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5','AA12BC') as VARBINARY) AS ColA`
- Set `ValidateExternalMetadata` to false on the destination component.
- Make sure both the source and destination have the same length for this column and that the data type is `DT_BTYES` on both components (in the Input and Output Properites pane on the Advanced Editor page).  This also applies to any transformations using the column during execution.